# Pandas Pivot table and keep two columns as combined identifier

Tags: python, pandas

So I have an external system that I get some data from.
It comes in this format:

```
+----+-----------+------------+-------+
| id | sessionId |  element   | value |
+----+-----------+------------+-------+
|  1 |         0 | extrainfo1 |    11 |
|  1 |         0 | extrainfo2 |    12 |
|  2 |         0 | extrainfo1 |    21 |
|  2 |         0 | extrainfo2 |    22 |
|  2 |         1 | extrainfo1 |    31 |
|  2 |         1 | extrainfo2 |    32 |
+----+-----------+------------+-------+
```

And I need it in this format:

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
| id | sessionId | extrainfo1 | extrainfo2 |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
|  1 |         0 |         11 |         12 |
|  2 |         0 |         21 |         22 |
|  2 |         1 |         31 |         32 |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I have tried

```
sf_pivot = sessionfields.pivot(index='id', columns=['sessionId','element'], values='value')
```

But that returns this:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| sessionId |     0      |            |     1      |            |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| element   | extrainfo1 | extrainfo2 | extrainfo1 | extrainfo2 |
| id        |            |            |            |            |
| 1         | 11         | 12         |            |            |
| 2         | 21         | 22         | 31         | 32         |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I tried to unstack that but didn't seem to work.

To have sessionId as a value in index or value when doing the pivot doesn't seem to work either, I get duplicate error on that.

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['id','sessionId'], columns='element', values='value')`

Comment: or `df.set_index(['id','sessionId','element']).unstack(-1).droplevel(0,1).reset_index()`